# WSO2 EI and Latency per transaction

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are evaluating wso2 ei for a system where the expected system latency is 1,3 seg for 200 TPS (concurrent users).

In our first tests we have an API Proxy that invokes 3 web services, exist a json transformer with payloadfactory and class mediators.

We have performed the tuning recommended by WSO2 EI for production envirment.

The results indicate that we have Latency per transaction between 2 and 3 seconds (average) with 16 TPS, which is very distant from the expected. The times of the services (response time) are excellent.

What is the capacity of WSO2 EI in relation to the response time (Latency per transaction) vs TPS?.

Some recommendations to improve the response times vs TPS?

thank for youy support;

Comment: The wso2ei itself can handle A LOT of TPS itself, so you will have to look somewhat deeper. E.g. how much of latency do the backend services? Do you create log records for each transaction? What does the class mediator (how long)? Employing analytics could give you more insight to answer these questions for you.

Comment: It really depends on your configuration, resources, backend and how you deployed your API. We had 1000 RPS on one node, really easy.